# jQuery move absolutely positioned div in increments

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I'm trying to create a really simple animation that moves along an absolutely positioned div when a button is pressed.

I can get it to jump to a specific value using.

```
    $("#rightArrow").click(function() {
    $(".projectImages").css(
        "left", '200px'
        );
});
```

But when I try to move it along by an increment it doesn't move at all.

```
$("#rightArrow").click(function() {
    $(".projectImages").css(
        "left", '+=200px'
        );
});
```

I've tried a few things but I can't seem to get it to work. Any suggestions here would be welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If .projectImages is selecting just one div, this should work:

```
$("#rightArrow").click(function() {        
    $(".projectImages").css(
        "left", (parseFloat($(this).css("left")) + 200) + 'px');
        );
});
```

ParseFloat reads the pixel value for the left position of the current element, but ignores the "px".

Answer (score 2):

I think increment value can only be used with the "animate" method.
From the description (http://api.jquery.com/animate/) :

> Animated properties can also be
>   relative. If a value is supplied with
>   a leading += or -= sequence of
>   characters, then the target value is
>   computed by adding or subtracting the
>   given number from the current value of
>   the property.

There's no mention of relative value in the description of the "css" method.

Comment: Yeah it seems you're right. If I animate it but set the duration to 0 it works fine. How odd.

'code'$("#rightArrow").click(function() {
     $('.projectImages').animate({left: '-=270'}, 0);
 });
'code'